# Show images within sticky on scroll

Tags: jquery, parallax, sticky, skrollr

I have a question in regards to using the skrollr parallax scrolling library. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

When the user scrolls down the page they will reach a div in that it sticks to the center of the viewport. As the user continues to scroll the images within the sticky will appear one by one. Once all images are shown it will continue to the next section. So ideally this whole sequence would be like a parallax effect.

I have a jsFiddle document with work in progress but would like to recieve further help.

https://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/b4sh7zs1/

```
<section class="blue"></section>
<section class="green"></section>
<section class="yellow"></section>
<div id="container">
When this div is hit it needs to be stuck (fixed) center of viewport until it finished animating images in one by one. 


<br />

<div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-0-top="opacity:0;" data-100-top="opacity:1;"></div>
<div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-100="opacity:0;" data-bottom-top="opacity:0;" data-top-bottom="opacity:1;"></div>
<div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-100="opacity:0;" data-bottom-top="opacity:0;" data-top-bottom="opacity:1;"></div>
</div>
<section class="red"></section>
<section class="orange"></section>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

using `position:sticky` might be the answer for you.

```
<section class="blue"></section>
<section class="green"></section>
<section class="yellow"></section>
<div id="container" class="sticky">
    When this div is hit it needs to be stuck (fixed) center of viewport until it finished animating images in one by one. 
    <br />
    <div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-0-top="opacity:0;" data-100-top="opacity:1;"></div>
    <div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-100="opacity:0;" data-bottom-top="opacity:0;" data-top-bottom="opacity:1;"></div>
    <div id="blue" data-anchor-target="#container" data-100="opacity:0;" data-bottom-top="opacity:0;" data-top-bottom="opacity:1;"></div>
</div>
<section class="red"></section>
<section class="orange"></section>
```

css

```
.sticky{
    position:sticky;
    top:calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

although you might want to change that `150px` in `top:calc(50% - 150px);` to something else if your `#container` div height is to be different.
https://jsfiddle.net/b4sh7zs1/3/ in action

if you want this to work in all browsers including polyfill, check out this article http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/
You can limit how far down the screen the div will stick for, by placing it inside a taller div, it stops moving once it reaches the bottom of the parent container.
This effect can bee seen in action here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html

Hope this helps steer you to a solution!